# Should I use SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with API restTemplate retry mechanism?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to write a kafka consumer application in spring-kafka. As consumer, I have to make sure I am not missing any record and all records should get processed.

My application design is like this :

```
Topics --> Read records from topic --> dump it into a table A in oracle database --> pick records from a table A --> call rest api to update records in system table B --> update response of API in table a --> commit records
```

**Retry Mechanism on API level :**

Now, if any of the records gets failed, means the response code is not as desired (400,500 etc..). We would retry those records 2 times.

**Retry Mechanism on Topic level :**

But, what if I got an error while committing offsets ? means, I need to have some kind of retry mechanism on the topic level as well. I went over documents and found an option :`SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L, 2L)));
    return factory;
}
```

Now, what I understand, suppose If I am not able to commit any offsets, then after adding above code, this will retry a delivery up to 2 times (3 delivery attempts) with a back off of 1 second. So, does this means, my whole flow will be replayed twice ? if this is true, then do I need to add retry mechanism on the API level separately ?

I am just trying to understand, how can I make my consumer application more resilient so I don't miss any record from processing and should have error mechanism to handle any error/missed records. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid situations where the offsets can't be committed (make sure the `max.poll.interval.ms` is sufficient).

But, yes, if committing the offsets fails (and `commitSync` is true) then the record will be redelivered to the application. If commitSync is `false`, the failure will simply be logged (or sent to your listener) and the "next" offset for that partition will have its offset committed later (presumably).

Adding retry at the application level (e.g. using a `RetryTemplate` in the listener adapter - via the container factory) will still suffer from the same problem; it also can cause a rebalance if the retries take too long.

If you really want to avoid reprocessing in this situation, you need to make your listener code idempotent - e.g. store the topic/partition/offset someplace to indicate you have already processed that record.